# Usar tipos de dados especificos como SMALLINT e MEDIUMINT ao invés de INT e marcar colunas com UNSIGNED é um exagero?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, mariadb

Falando de bancos de dados, sabemos que eles possuem vários data types para serem utilizados em cada situação especifica. Mas, seguir os tipos de dados a risca pode ser considera um exagero na maioria dos casos ou é sempre recomendado, mesmo dando mais trabalho para o desenvolvedor?

E aproveitando a questão, sobre o UNSIGNED (que para quem não sabe, serve para informar ao banco que aquela coluna não aceitará valores negativos. Isso também aumenta o valor positivo limite da coluna), também é um exagero usá-lo em todas as colunas que não irão receber valores negativos (que na maior parte dos casos, serão a maioria)? Usar o UNSGINED, além de aumentar o limite, garante melhor perfomance ou não? Já que a quantidade de valores possíveis continua a mesma, eu acredito que não.

Tenho pouca experiência com bancos de dados. Infelizmente é um recurso que embora utilizemos sempre, acabamos deixando de lado e fazendo o que todo mundo faz.

Se tiver algo a mais que se encaixe com a pergunta e quiserem acrescentar, fiquem à vontade.

Answer (score 2):

Depende do contexto. Se estivermos falando de um protótipo ou de tabelas que numca serão muito grandes, pode ser um exagero investir muito tempo otimizando datatypes. Porém, se forem tabelas que alcançarão milhões ou bilhões de linhas, cada byte economizado em uma linha representará vários Gigabytes no seu dataset. Isso certamente terá impacto no espaço de armazenamento e na performance.

Há também a questão semântica, onde usar uma restrição como UNSIGNED, por exemplo, pode evitar dados incorretos no seu banco de dados por algum bug na aplicação.

Portanto, sempre que possível entenda a natureza do dado e use datatypes corretos, mas seja coerente com o seu caso particular, pois não é nada incomum usar datatypes "errados" em protótipos ou aplicações menores.